# Rails search form- not sure how to get it to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, rails-routing

I'm trying to add a search form on my main home page of my rails app that can search across the candidate model to see that if I type in the name of a candidate, it displays pictures of possible candidates, and clicking on them gets to their candidate pages.

Question: the search form displays on the home page, but then I get a routing error: No route matches [GET] "/search"

Here is what the code looks like in views/home/index.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag("/search", :method => "get") do %>
<%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
<%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

Search controller:

```
def index
@candidates = Candidate.search(params[:name])
end
```

Search view (views/search/index.html.erb):

```
<h1> Here are your search results: </h1>
<% @candidates.each do |candidate| %>
<%= link_to image_tag(candidate.picture, :size => "100x100", :alt => "Edit Entry"),     candidate%>
<% end%>
```

Candidate model:

```
def self.search(name)
 where('name LIKE ?', "%#{name}%")
end
```

Rake routes:

```
candidates_show GET    /candidates/show(.:format)     candidates#show
candidates_new GET    /candidates/new(.:format)      candidates#new
donations_index GET    /donations/index(.:format)     donations#index
home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)          home#index
import_candidates POST   /candidates/import(.:format)   candidates#import
candidates GET    /candidates(.:format)          candidates#index
POST   /candidates(.:format)          candidates#create
new_candidate GET    /candidates/new(.:format)      candidates#new
edit_candidate GET    /candidates/:id/edit(.:format) candidates#edit
candidate GET    /candidates/:id(.:format)      candidates#show
PUT    /candidates/:id(.:format)      candidates#update
DELETE /candidates/:id(.:format)      candidates#destroy
root        /                              home#index
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited it a bit!

Comment: Looks you maybe you are using the home controller but the search code is in your search controller.  Perhaps move that search method to your home controller.  Will need to change self to Candidate

Comment: I still get the same routing error. I tried adding a route to search, but wasn't sure what to match it to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form tag points to `search` but there is no route called `search`. Like suggested above, either move the `index` method from your search controller to your home controller or add the `search` route in your routes.rb like

```
match "search" => "search#index"
```

Comment: I still get the same routing error. I tried adding a route to search, but wasn't sure what to match it to...

Comment: It worked! Question: the search isn't effective at filtering the candidates (it just shows the pictures of all of them). Is there anything that I'm doing with the SQL command?

Comment: Look in your log file to see what query is performed `tail -f log/development.log` from within your app root folder

Comment: Yossarian, should I have the the candidate search code (i.e. all the SQL stuff) in a search model? I feel like that's what is screwing up. The output reads as follows: Started GET "/assets/home.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-11 15:43:04 -0700
Served asset /home.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-11 15:43:04 -0700
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/Moore.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-11 15:43:04 -0700
Served asset /Moore.jpg - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Comment: Now have it now in the Candidate model, which implies the `where clause` will be executed on the candidates table. So it will look something like: `select * from candidates where candidate.name like %whut%`

Comment: What you are looking for in your log file are the SQL queries that rails creates. Not the GET requests :) Analyze those SQL queries